# atd load and interval configuration

Tags: configuration, command-line, scripts, batch

I've been using `at -q b now` and `batch` commands recently for a project of mine. The problem is that no matter how I modify the conf file it will not take my changes into account.

The exec line in `/etc/init/atd.conf` is as follows :

```
exec atd -l 2.5 -b 10
```

I restart atd with `sudo service atd restart` but it's still only running the commands every 2mn (I thought atd default was 60s anyways?). At this point I'm not even sure the load is being taken into account either.

Can anyone help with this? I'm running ubuntu 11.10 (64b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok answering my own question here. Sounds pretty stupid but I couldn't try this before because of the load on my server.

`sudo service atd restart` does not seem to reload the `atd.conf` file. However, rebooting the machine does.

I don't know if this is expected behavior. If it is and you know why I would be more than happy to hear you on it.